# Is it possible to do code coverage analysis with Visual Studio 2019 when running manual tests

Tags: code-coverage, visual-studio-2019

I have a web application developed in Visual Studio 2019 (free Community edition), running on .NET Core 2.2

Because it's a web app, unit tests don't really help. But I would like to see if I have tested all the code when doing manual testing. Is this possible?

If you care to suggest a way of automating the testing of a complex web app, that would be nice, provided it isn't too open ended a question.